# How to sort an array of datas for csv column using php?

Tags: php, csv

I was creating a `.csv` downloadable file using php. I need to sort out the data alphabetically by `first_name` so I tried using `asort('$user->first_name');` and it ends up an error. I'll show the whole code maybe you guys can help me out.

```
public function getTransportationReport()
    {
    header...

    $file = fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );

    fputcsv( $file, array('Departure Location', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Group Name', 'Unit', 'Unit Number', 'Phone Number', 'Email Address') );

    $rowed = array();
    $auth_event = \App\Group::find( session()->get( 'event-id' ) );
    $bookings = \App\EventBookings::where('group_id', '=', $auth_event->group_id)->where('chalet_id', '!=', 0)->get();
        if ( $bookings->count() ) {
            foreach ($bookings as $booking) {
            $event_group = \App\EventGroup::find($booking->eg_id);
                if ( $event_group ) {
                $chalet = \App\Chalet::find($booking->chalet_id);
                    if ( $chalet ) {
                    $transpoCharges = \App\EventBookingCharges::where('booking_id', '=', $booking->booking_id)->where('charge_key', 'LIKE', 'transportation')->get();
                        if ( $transpoCharges->count() ) {
                            foreach ($transpoCharges as $transpoCharge) {
                            $jdecode = json_decode($transpoCharge->json);
                            $user = \App\User::find($transpoCharge->user_id);
                            $paidCharges = \App\EventBookingCharges::where('booking_id', '=', $booking->booking_id)->where('status','=',1)->where('user_id','=',$user->user_id)->sum('amount');

                                if ( $user ) {
                                  $rowed[] = array(
                                  $jdecode->location,
                                  $user->first_name,
                                  $user->last_name,
                                  $event_group->name,
                                  $chalet->name,
                                  $chalet->unit_no,
                                  $user->phone,
                                  $user->email,
                                 );

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        $data = $rowed;
            foreach ($data as $row) {
            fputcsv($file, $row);
            }
        }

    exit();
        if ( Auth::user()->user_level == 2 ) {
            return Redirect::to( $auth_event->alias . '/app/etranspo' );
        } else {
            return Redirect::to( '/app/' . $auth_event->alias . '/etranspo' );
        }
    }
```

If I click the button it will only show `file not found` but if I right click the button and select `save as` it will download a `.csv` file with errors saying `error ReportsController.php line 490` [ the line where asort($user->first_name); is ] and `Indirect modification of overloaded property App\User::$first_name has no effect`

Comment: Please show error log, helps a lot.

Comment: @Flummox It says `error ReportsController.php line 490` [the line where asort($user->first_name); is] and `Indirect modification of overloaded property App\User::$first_name has no effect`

Comment: add it to your question.

Comment: The line that's causing your problem should be in the example. Why was it dropped?

Comment: @Christoph because I thought it was useless. The code on the top is the working version. All that I need is how to sort by first name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to sort the array data like this:

```
$data = $rowed;

// sort the data by a user specified function
uasort($data, function($a, $b) {
  // compare by first name (index 1 in the array)
  return strcmp($a[1], $b[1]);
});

foreach ($data as $row) {
  fputcsv($file, $row);
}
```

You can find the documentation on uasort [here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.uasort.php).

Comment: Hey @Christoph, sir, thank you very much. It worked although you code needs made my data sorted in descending so I changed the less than sign into greater than sign. Again thank you very much

Comment: @Newbie Seems I used c++ syntax (`std::sort` takes a function that returns true if an element is smaller, stupid me). php uses 3 way compare: -1 for smaller, 0 for equal, 1 for bigger. Fixed it to use strcmp.